# Find all files and unzip specific file to local folder

Tags: linux, find

```
find -name archive.zip -exec unzip {} file.txt \;
```

This command finds all files named archive.zip and unzips file.txt to the folder that I execute the command from, is there a way to unzip the file to the same folder where the .zip file was found? I would like file.txt to be unzipped to folder1.

```
folder1\archive.zip
folder2\archive.zip
```

I realize $dirname is available in a script but I'm looking for a one line command if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get file directory path from file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121091/get-file-directory-path-from-file-path)

Comment: Try $(dirname {}) maybe?

Comment: find -name archive.zip -exec echo $(dirname {}) \; $dirname appears to be '.'

Answer (score 0):

@iheartcpp - I successfully ran three alternatives using the same base command...

```
find . -iname "*.zip"
```

... which is used to provide the list of / to be passed as an argument to the next command.

**Alternative 1: find with `-exec` + Shell Script (unzips.sh)**

File unzips.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This will unzip the zip files in the same directory as the zip are

for f in "$@" ; do
    unzip -o -d `dirname $f` $f
done
```

Use this alternative like this:

```
find . -iname '*.zip' -exec ./unzips.sh {} \;
```

**Alternative 2: find with `| xargs` _ Shell Script (unzips)**

Same `unzips.sh` file.

Use this alternative like this:

```
find . -iname '*.zip' | xargs ./unzips.sh
```

**Alternative 3: all commands in the same line (no .sh files)**

Use this alternative like this:

```
find . -iname '*.zip' | xargs sh -c 'for f in $@; do unzip -o -d `dirname $f` $f; done;'
```

---

Of course, there are other alternatives but hope that the above ones can help.